# linq query from more tables

Tags: c#, linq, select, join

```
public ActionResult myItems() {

        var dataContext = new RecordsDataContext();
        MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();         
        string CurrentUserName = myObject.UserName.ToString();    

       var user = from i in dataContext.myUsers
                   where i.userName ==CurrentUserName
                   select i.id;

        var items=from j in dataContext.OtherUsers
                   where j.id_user==user   /*error:operator '==' cannot be aplied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Linq.Iquerable<int>'*/
                   select j;



           return View(items);

    }
```

Please help me with this error

Comment: If my answer suits your question, accept it to remove your question from unanswered list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually user from the first query is not a single int result. You need to check if user.Count() is not 0 and you could use user.First() to retrieve first row result.

But I suggest to use join (something like that):

```
public ActionResult myItems() {
    var dataContext = new RecordsDataContext();
    var query = from i in dataContext.myItems
                join ou in dataContext.OtherUsers
                on i.id_user equals ou.id_user //check real reference, since I don't know
                join mu in dataContext.myUsers
                on ou.id_user equals mu.id_user
                where mu.username == Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString()
                select i;
    return View(query);
}
```